# remove item from array in javascript based on other array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist, javascript-objects

I want to remove completely an item from the list, below is the list

```
var list = [{id: 1, match_number: 1, name: "match1"},
     {id: 2, match_number: 2, name: "match2"},
     {id: 3, match_number: 3, name: "match3"},
     {id: 4, match_number: 4, name: "match4"},
     {id: 5, match_number: 5, name: "match5"}]
```

I want remove `match_number` completely from the list, and want to achieve like

```
var list = [{id: 1, name: "match1"},
     {id: 2, name: "match2"},
     {id: 3, name: "match3"},
     {id: 4, name: "match4"},
     {id: 5, name: "match5"}]
```

Below is the code where I achieved the result for single item, but I have an array where key are given like **`['match_number','id']`**. on the basis of this I want to remove item from the main list.

How can I solve this?

```
//code for single item
var listitem = list.map((i) => {
    const {match_number,...item} = i;
    return item;
});
```

Comment: So you want it to be removed from the original array?

Comment: no i dont want it to remove from original array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `map` on the `list` array to modify the existing array of objects to not to have `match_number` key.

```js
var list = [
 {id: 1, match_number: 1, name: "match1"},
 {id: 2, match_number: 2, name: "match2"},
 {id: 3, match_number: 3, name: "match3"},
 {id: 4, match_number: 4, name: "match4"},
{id: 5, match_number: 5, name: "match5"}
];

list.map(obj => delete obj.match_number);
console.log(list);
```

For your array of keys which you want to remove and also for not affecting the original `list` array you can go with this,

```js
var list = [
 {id: 1, match_number: 1, name: "match1"},
 {id: 2, match_number: 2, name: "match2"},
 {id: 3, match_number: 3, name: "match3"},
 {id: 4, match_number: 4, name: "match4"},
{id: 5, match_number: 5, name: "match5"}
];
var res = [];
var removeArray = ['match_number','id'];
list.forEach((obj) => {
  let tempObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key)=>{
    if(removeArray.indexOf(key) === -1){
      tempObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
  });
  res.push(tempObj);
});
console.log(res);
console.log(list);
```

Comment: but i want remove item from the list in an immutable way and want on the based of other array

Comment: @tapandave where is your other array in question? And where in the question you have mentioned `immutable` way?

Comment: i have mentioned below that based on other array that is ['match_number','id'] i want to remove keys from the list

Comment: @tapandave cool, check the edited answer. I have added another snippet there. Let me know if there is still some issues with that.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the attributes to remove in an array like `attrToRemove` below and use `delete` along with `map` and `forEach`

```js
var list = [
 {id: 1, match_number: 1, name: "match1"},
 {id: 2, match_number: 2, name: "match2"},
 {id: 3, match_number: 3, name: "match3"},
 {id: 4, match_number: 4, name: "match4"},
{id: 5, match_number: 5, name: "match5"}
];

var attrToRemove =  ['match_number','id'];

list.map(obj => attrToRemove.forEach(val=> delete obj[val]));

console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your keys and remove them by using `destructuring` and `rest`:

```js
var list = [
 {id: 1, match_number: 1, name: "match1"},
 {id: 2, match_number: 2, name: "match2"},
 {id: 3, match_number: 3, name: "match3"},
 {id: 4, match_number: 4, name: "match4"},
 {id: 5, match_number: 5, name: "match5"}
];
var keys =  ['match_number', 'id'];

list = list.map(item => {
    var x, rest = item;
    keys.forEach(key => {
        ({ [key]: x, ...rest } = rest);
    });
    return rest;
});

console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Jquery+ES6

You can also use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to get required result using [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator.

**DEMO**

```js
var list = [{id: 1, match_number: 1, name: "match1"},
 {id: 2, match_number: 2, name: "match2"},
 {id: 3, match_number: 3, name: "match3"},
 {id: 4, match_number: 4, name: "match4"},
{id: 5, match_number: 5, name: "match5"}]

let removeKeys = ['match_number','id'];
let result = $.map(list,(o)=>{
 $.each(removeKeys, (i,v)=> delete o[v]);
 return o;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

## ES6

You could also use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method of array to get the required result. With using of [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

**DEMO**

```js
var list = [{id: 1, match_number: 1, name: "match1"},
 {id: 2, match_number: 2, name: "match2"},
 {id: 3, match_number: 3, name: "match3"},
 {id: 4, match_number: 4, name: "match4"},
{id: 5, match_number: 5, name: "match5"}]

let removeKeys = ['match_number','id'];
let result = list.reduce((r,o)=>{
 removeKeys.forEach(v=> delete o[v]);
 return r.concat(o);
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```